# What should we call our main chat room?

Tags: discussion

Our main chat room is currently called "Vegetarianism" which is kind of dull.

Other sites' rooms have more interesting/witty/creative names (list of examples stolen from a similar post on Ask Ubuntu meta) such as

- /dev/chat (Unix  &Linux)
- Root Access (Super User)
- The 2nd Monitor (Code Review)
- The Nineteenth Byte (Programming Puzzles & Code Golf)
- The Bridge (Arqade)
- The Heap - Consultancy (Database Admins)
- The h Bar (Physics)
- The Periodic Table (Chemistry)
- The Hangar (Aviation)
- The Frying Pan (Cooking)

Should we rename our room, and if so, what should we call it?

Please make one suggestion per answer (so if you have three ideas, you would post three answers) The most upvoted suggestion will be implemented (I'm not sure when, after a reasonable period I guess?)

Answer (score 10):

I will add my two cents with

## **The Greenhouse**

Answer (score 7):

This won't be very original, maybe there will be more interesting proposals, but I suggest:

### The Garden

Answer (score 5):

Potentially caters too much to the myth of "veg*ns only eat salad", but

### The Salad Bar

Comment: Hah I like it though, could be a little tongue-in-cheek :)

Answer (score 5):

Suggested by my mum :)

## The Veg Patch

Answer (score 3):

### The Green Room

Comment: I think this has the potential to be confused with [green rooms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_room) in show business.

Answer (score 2):

### **Rabbits' talk**

or something similar...

Answer (score 0):

### The Rabbits' corner

Answer (score -1):

### The Harvest

Comment: This one kind of has a dark undertone...

Comment: @RamonMelo Why?

Comment: Pretty sure there are dozens of heavy metal songs featuring "The Harvest" in some way.

Comment: @RamonMelo I have no clue about that.

Answer (score -1):

### Mother Earth

Answer (score -1):

### DisCowsion place